# PHP locking a transaction

Tags: php, locking

I have a auction website in PHP, and I want immediate payment on whatever amount the customer bids (I will refund all non-winning bids later). Say my item currently is $10 and I have customers A and B.

If A puts in a $15 bid, then I request A to put in his credit card info right away and charge $15 from the card. The bid doesn't count as a bid until the credit card processing is completed.

Say while A was entering his credit card info B puts in a bid as well. A finished entering the credit card info first and clicked submit.  If B's bid is lower than or equal to 15 it will prompt to B something like "Sorry someone put a higher bid while you were putting in your credit card info". If B's bid was > 15 then of course it will just charge that amount from B's card and the latest price is B's bid.

Now my problem is that during the period my site sends a request to charge A's card for $15 (to let's say Paypal), B should not be able to make a payment at the sametime (otherwise we will be charging both people's card). B has to wait until A's payment is completed before my server can process B's "Submit payment" request. And when my server does process the request it should check if B's bid is higher or lower than the latest payment submitted ($15 by A).

So basically I want to "lock" the "Submit payment" function for all other users when A's payment is sending to Paypal and waiting response from Paypal. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What if the bid goes up by $0.05? Will you charge my card $0.05 or refund my original $10 bid and charge $10.05?

Comment: we keep track of your previous bids, so we'll charge $0.05 in this case

Comment: From a consumer's point of view, I would be annoyed at seeing dozens of less than $1 charges on my statement.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, the items are usually pretty high value and the incrementals will be in the $100s range

Comment: I would say make all bidders pre-approve a certain minimum limit to participate. Then you charge the winning bid at the end.

Comment: common consumer-producer problem, the problem is that PHP has no symaphore, so I suggest to make a global flag, like inside XML file whenever A or B submit the flag goes to false. after finishing they release the flag for another procedure. if you think that might help I can post an answer with more details.

Comment: actually php has symaphore, take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php)

Comment: Semaphore is not really scalable, as it would only affect a single server. You need to look at doing locking in the database or another type of store.

Comment: @datasage - that's why I suggested XML flag.

Comment: And where is this XML flag stored? And how difficult would it be to implement a transactional system on this?

Answer (score 1):

Use your database for this. For every bid, create a row; use a "status" column containing e.g. 1=bid amount entered; 2=CC info entered/verifying; 3=bid accepted. After the charge has been authorized (ie. between status 2 and 3), do a query to check if the bid amount is still sufficient, and only then charge the CC (and simultaneously update the status to 3.)

If the bid has been superseded because someone else has completed a higher bid, reject the bid.